# Form validation with jQuery in PHP self referencing form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a form using a jQuery form validation plug-in.
It's working well in a HTML page. But when I copy-paste the same code into a form in a PHP page whose action is `PHP_SELF` form validation isn't working.

My code:

```
<form id='registerForm' name='registerForm' method='post' action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
</form>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jq213.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        $("#registerForm").validate({
            rules:{
                name:{
                    required:true,
                    minlength:2
                },
                email:{
                    required:true,
                    email:true
                },
            },
            messages:{
                name:{
                    required:"pls enter your name",
                    minlength:"minimum 2 char for name"
                },
                email:{
                    required:"required",
                    email:"Enter a valid email"
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Why is it not working in a PHP self referencing form? If any more information is needed please tell me.

Comment: I suggest you use HTML 5 instead of that <input type="text" minlength="2" required> for name and <input type="email" required> for email

Comment: What's the output of `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`?

Comment: @rapidooo  how to do that? What is the syntax for that?

Comment: @MyGGaN  i can pass value to server what user gives input. but form validation not working

Comment: Does it really have to be jquery?

Comment: @rapidooo Or what do u suggest for?

Comment: <input type="text" minlength="2" required>  and <input type="email" required>

Comment: yeah thats great suggestion. but i need  additional something. so i need jquery. May u help in jquery?

Comment: i discovered that, my code is ok. but its not working for a unknown reason. thank u all for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq213.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="validate.min.js"></script>
```

These two lines of codes are not working. And except this everything is ok. **I have tested.** Any how make these plugins work.

Comment: I was using Ubuntu. And my OS didn't allow the plugins first as they were copied from another place.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='registerForm' name='registerForm' method='post' action="" >
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email"   />
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
</form>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq213.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        $("#registerForm").validate({
            rules:{
                name:{
                    required:true,
                    minlength:2
                },
                email:{
                    required:true,
                    email:true
                },
            },
            messages:{
                name:{
                    required:"pls enter your name",
                    minlength:"minimum 2 char for name"
                },
                email:{
                    required:"required",
                    email:"Enter a valid email"
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
<form id='registerForm' name='registerForm' method='post' action="" >
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="2" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jq213.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="validate.min.js"></script>


<script> 
$(function() {
    $("#registerForm").validate({
        rules:{
            name:{
                required:true,
                minlength:2
            },
            email:{
                required:true,
                email:true
            },
        },
        messages:{
            name:{
                required:"pls enter your name",
                minlength:"minimum 2 char for name"
            },
            email:{
                required:"required",
                email:"Enter a valid email"
            }
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but actually i need jquery

Comment: Did you import the proper libraries needed? like <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: yes, i did, i downloaded those files and i have included those

Comment: Try to enclose with $(function() { }) your jquery code;

Answer (score 1):

You code works fine and the problem is that you are missing your jQuery file. Add those 2 line of code and it should work.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`

AND ALSO *IMPORTANT*

Use `$().ready(function ()` ~~

```
    $().ready(function () {
    $("#registerForm").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "pls enter your name",
                minlength: "minimum 2 char for name"
            },
            email: {
                required: "required",
                email: "Enter a valid email"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try 3 things:

1. Add type="text/javascript" in your third `"<script></script>"`
2. Start with $(document).ready(function(){}) before using jQuery functions;
3. View page source and try clicking to your src link to found whether they are working or not! If not, maybe the link has changed to wrong when you transfer to PHP.

Hope it will help!